# How to add text in input depending on a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wrote this code

```js
$("#workDesign label").on("click", function() {
  var input = $(this).children("input");
  var tag = $(this).text();
  if (input.prop("checked")) {
    input.parent().addClass("selected");
    alert(tag);
    $("#workDesignTags").val(tag);
  } else {
    input.parent().removeClass("selected");
  }
});
var tagList;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formRow labelBox col3 dropDownMobile" id="workDesign">

  <input type="text" name="tags" id="workDesignTags">

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 1">
    <span class="textBox">Value 1
              </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 2">
    <span class="textBox">Value 2
                      </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 3">
    <span class="textBox">Value 3
                              </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 4">
    <span class="textBox">Value 4
                                      </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

How to do the value added, rather than replacing the old one? How to make the value removed from total value, if checkbox is unchecked? I have the layout just changes the values in input.

Comment: Have you tried `$("#workDesignTags").val($("#workDesignTags").val() + tag);`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```js
$("#workDesign label").on("click", function() {
  var input = $(this).children("input");
  var tag = $(this).text();
  if (input.prop("checked")) {
    input.parent().addClass("selected");
   val = $("#workDesignTags").val().trim() + tag;
    $("#workDesignTags").val(val);
  } else {
    input.parent().removeClass("selected");
  }
});
var tagList;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formRow labelBox col3 dropDownMobile" id="workDesign">

  <input type="text" name="tags" id="workDesignTags">

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 1">
    <span class="textBox">Value 1
              </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 2">
    <span class="textBox">Value 2
                      </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 3">
    <span class="textBox">Value 3
                              </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 4">
    <span class="textBox">Value 4
                                      </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#workDesign label").on("click", function() {
  var input = $(this).children("input");
  var tag = $(this).text();
  if (input.prop("checked")) {
    input.parent().addClass("selected");
    alert(tag);
    $("#workDesignTags").val($.trim($("#workDesignTags").val() + tag));
  } else {
    input.parent().removeClass("selected");
  }
});
var tagList;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formRow labelBox col3 dropDownMobile" id="workDesign">

  <input type="text" name="tags" id="workDesignTags">

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 1">
    <span class="textBox">Value 1
          </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 2">
    <span class="textBox">Value 2
                  </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 3">
    <span class="textBox">Value 3
                          </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 4">
    <span class="textBox">Value 4
                                  </span>
  </label>
</div>
```

You could get the input value and add that with the new value and set it as input value

Another option could be like this

```js
var value = "";
$("#workDesign label").on("click", function() {
  var input = $(this).children("input");
  var tag = $(this).text();
  if (input.prop("checked")) {
    input.parent().addClass("selected");
    value += $.trim(tag)
    $("#workDesignTags").val(value);
  } else {
    input.parent().removeClass("selected");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formRow labelBox col3 dropDownMobile" id="workDesign">

  <input type="text" name="tags" id="workDesignTags">

  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 1">
    <span class="textBox">Value 1
          </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 2">
    <span class="textBox">Value 2
                  </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 3">
    <span class="textBox">Value 3
                          </span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="design" value="Value 4">
    <span class="textBox">Value 4
                                  </span>
  </label>
</div>
```